# get object key value base on dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
console.log(x, obj.fares) //return undefined
```

output

```
adultFare
Object {adultFare: "9.00", childFare: null, seniorCitizenFare: null, disabledFare: null,}
```

How can I get adultDare value? do I have to loop the key? I expect obj.fares.x can get 9.00 since x's value is adultFare.

Comment: You just need `obj.adultFare` if `adultFare` is stored in a variable use `obj[someVariable]`

Comment: I'm sure I can help, but I don't think I'm understanding the question. obj.fares has the object. obj.fares.adultFare === "9.00"

Comment: Ah, you want obj.fares[x].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just:

```
console.log(obj.fares[x]);
```

```js
var obj = {"fares":{adultFare: "9.00", childFare: null, seniorCitizenFare: null, disabledFare: null}},
    x = "adultFare";

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = obj.fares[x];
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @Jennifer you have to use bracket notation then. see the updates and demo.

Comment: now I know when to use bracket notation vs dot notation! is there other different use case?

Answer (score -1):

I believe it should be **obj.adultFare**

Try using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#some) as it has some really good functions.

If you are trying the get the actually value in the adultfare has you could also try pluck

> _.pluck(collection, path)

Pluck will give a return of all the adult fares in the array, so if you pass the single array in it will give you that one fare.

It has examples in the docs.

Comment: uh no.. any simpler solution?

Comment: Adding dependencies for simple operations seems like overkill. It's kind of like recommending everyone use Jquery if they're having trouble doing anything with DOM manipulation, when sometimes it's quite unnecessary.